# How to split an image vertically using the command line?

Tags: command-line, images, imagemagick, split, image-manipulation

Say I have a large 800x5000 image; how would I split that into 5 separate images with dimensions 800x1000 using the command line?

Comment: Please don't add the solution to your Q. Mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 55):

Solved it using [ImageMagick's convert](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) -crop geometry +repage:

```
convert -crop 100%x20% +repage image.png image.png
```

Comment: If you want to apply this to a batch of files, try this:
`ls -1 *.png | sed 's,.*,& &,' | xargs -n 2 convert -crop 100%x20% +repage`

Comment: Okay, so `100%x20%` splits vertically and `20%x100%` splits horizontally.

Comment: To place the exports in a subfolder, create that folder and add it to the "sed" part of the command: `ls -1 *.png | sed 's,.*,& subfolder_name/&,' | xargs -n 2 convert -crop 100%x20% +repage`

Comment: To split a scan of two pages, I had to use the option `-deconstruct`. Without it one of the two files came out as the original with one side blank.

Comment: Seems no need to +repage in latest versions?

Comment: Not working anymore

Answer (score 31):

Using ImageMagick:

```
$ convert -crop 800x1000 image.png cropped_%d.png
```

Will create a sequence of files named `cropped_1.png`, `cropped_2.png`, and so on.

#### References

- [Tile Cropping, sub-dividing one image into multiple images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile)
- [ImageMagick v6 Examples -- Cutting and Bordering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/)

Comment: The OP said that this solved it using `convert -crop geometry +repage`. For example: `convert -crop 100%x20% +repage image.png image.png`.

Comment: `+repage` [considerations](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) re: image offset capable formats etc.

Comment: How does this compare to @shley's answer?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai it's essentially the same, they're using percentages so it will split any size image into 5 vertical slices instead of being written specifically for the 800x5000 case

Answer (score 10):

Using the "tiles" functionality:

```
convert image.png -crop 1x5@ out-%d.png
```

https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: Newer docs: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop ('You can add the @ to the geometry argument to equally divide the image into the number of tiles generated.')

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick would crash on me, for the image being too big for it to handle, so I had to resort to other methods.

I ended up using the Python Image Library.

A quick and dirty answer to the OP question follows:

```python
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("YourImage.yourformat")

for h in range(0, im.height, 1000):
     nim = im.crop((0, h, im.width-1, min(im.height, h+1000)-1))
     nim.save("PartialImage." + str(h) + ".yourformat")
```

The above code has the final sizes hardcoded, but it can be easily transformed into an full blow script of its own with all inputs parameterized. If one ever needs such a thing.